# Problems with my motherboard and snap

Tags: nvidia, bluetooth, snap, motherboard

Today I have seen a lot of unfortunate events. After I installed python extension for vsCode I noted that the apps started to glitch; first slack, then firefox until my PC freezed. When I rebooted I saw an error **like**:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean x/x files, x/x blocks
```

I googled it and people were saying that it was a problem with Nvidia so I reinstalled the nvidia drivers in a secure boot with:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Doing this I was able to boot normally, but then I recieved this for a brief moments:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean x/x files, x/x blocks
[   6.78546] Bluetooth: hci0: alformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
```

And after my login I tried to open firefox and slack and recieved this in the console:

```
cmd_run.go:1055: WARNING: cannot start document portal: Expected portal at "/run/user/1000/doc", got "home/user/.cache/doc"
/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-2.scope is not a snap cgroup
```

Extra: Ubuntu doesnt recognize audio output/input devices nor the bluetooth.

When I executed:

```
/etc/X11/default-display-manager
```

I recieved outputs and this error:

```
runtime directory '/run/user/1000' is not owned by uid 1000 as it should
```

pls save me

Comment: In About section it says my graphics are llvmpipe(LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits) but I have a Nvidia 3060 12GB

Comment: "/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean x/x files, x/x blocks" is not an error. It is a normal message produced at boot. I wish this message were not displayed, because everyone who has a boot problem, thinks it is an informative error about the issue. *It isn't.*

Comment: If I were you, I would focus more on what I did here " After I installed python extension for vsCode" and how to reverse that. Messing with Python = formula for breaking your system. If you did Thing X, and then your problems started....better suspect Thing X.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/run/user/1000 is not owned by UID 1000, as it should](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1481797/run-user-1000-is-not-owned-by-uid-1000-as-it-should)