# /run/user/1000 is not owned by UID 1000, as it should

Tags: permissions, sudo, snap, root, chmod

So I have this error going on, and its the origin of a lot of errors with snap that I'm recieving. So when I execute:

```
$ systemctl status display-manager
```

Recieved some text and:

```
gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user jhon(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
pam_systemd(gdm-password:session): Runtime directory '/run/user/1000' is not owned by UID 1000, as it should
pam_systemd(gdm-password:session): Not setting $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, as the directory is not in order.
gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
 Gdm: process -888 was already dead.r
```

So this line telling that the **$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR** was not set I suspect that is the origin to my snap problems like not being able to open firefox and receiving:

```
cmd_run.go:1055: WARNING: cannot start document portal: Expected portal at "run/user/1000/doc", got "/home/pablo/.cache/doc"
/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-2.scope is not a snap cgroup
```

Even if I chmod this it doesnt work.
help pls

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have lost the ownership of the snap folder or, probably, the entire home folder.
In your home folder by running `ls -l`, you have two columns indicating the owner and the group assigned to every element. The error that you're describing, occurs when your primary group is different from the one assigned to the home folder.
First of all make sure that you have the correct default group.
By running the `id` command you should see something like `uid=1000(USER) gid=1000(GROUP)`. This means that the user `USER` has the group `GROUP` as primary. If the group is not the default, change it with `sudo usermod -g GROUP USER` (changing GROUP and USER with the correct group you want as primary and your user) 
Now, `cd /home` and then run `chown -R USER:GROUP HOME_FOLDER/` (changing USER and GROUP as before and HOME_FOLDER with your home.